# How to get all characters between dash and opening bracket?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

How can I get all characters between **DASH** and **BRACKET** with C#?

string x = "PU - **XX** (AYT)"

I would like to get **XX**.
The dash [**-**] and the bracket [**(**] are constant.

Comment: You mean "open parenthesis"?

Comment: Do you also want the spaces after the dash and before the parenthesis?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: So many people happen to mix up brackets "[]", braces "{}" and parenthesis "()".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Substring()` function to get the Required Part of `String`.

```
            string x = "PU - XX (AYT)";
            int end = x.IndexOf("(");
            int begin = x.IndexOf("-");    
            string requiredPart=x.Substring(begin+1, (end - begin)-1);
```

variable requiredPart contains string between `-` and `(`

Answer (score 2):

You can get those with a combination of `string.IndexOf(string)` and `string.substring(start,length)` or use the `string.split(char)` - method.

Another way is using regular expressions. But as a beginner I would suggest the string - functions as they help you *understand* what is going on. RegExes are not really easy to understand for starters.

You should find deep explanations to these methods in the msdn:

IndexOf:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

SubString:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

Split:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Regex: `"- (.+)\("`

Define it as a group within a Regex string using `(group)` and make sure you escape you `(` you are matching by using `\(`. The `.+` then means one or more of anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = "PU - XX (AYT)";
int s = str.IndexOf('-');    
if(s < 0)                                             //make sure string contains a dash
    return "";
else
{
    int e = str.IndexOf('(', s + 1)                   //start looking for bracket 
                                                      //from this point forward

    return (e >= 0? str.Substring(s + 1, e - s) : ""); //ensure it contains a bracket too
}
```

Comment: Add some comment as well, it helps

Comment: @Lokesh: Thanks, added some comments. Thought the code was self-explanatory though.

Answer (score 1):

Here, this regex works to find just the center section of your string anything between "- " and " (" This automatically excludes the spaces.

```
(?<=- ).*(?= \()
```